# Are bounds known for the maximum determinant of a (0,1)-matrix of specified size and with a specifed number of 1s?

Tags: matrices, determinants

The problems of determining the maximum determinant of an $n \times n$ $(0,1)$-matrix and the spectral problem of determining exactly which other determinants can possibly occur are both reasonably well studied.

What I'd like to know is whether there are bounds known if the number of 1s in the matrix is specified.

In other words, if we let $f(n,k)$ denote the maximum determinant of an $n \times n$ $(0,1)$-matrix with exactly $k$ ones (in total, not per row), then are there any known bounds on the values for $f(n,k)$?

I've searched Math Reviews and Googled it, but all the papers that I have found refer to the maximum over the entire set of $n \times n$ matrices.

Edit: Here is a plot of the maximum determinant of a binary $6 \times 6$ matrix with $k$ 1s, where $0 \leq k \leq 36$ (as long as I haven't messed up the computation).

[image: Maximum determinant]

Edit 2: Here is the analogous plot for $7 \times 7$ matrices.

[image: Maximum determinants for n=7]

Edit 3: Here is a plot of the bound given by Peter Mueller's post, together with the actual values for n=7.

[image]

Comment: No literature I know addresses your precise question. Zivkovic in his 2005 arxiv  classification paper comes closest; by using certain similarities in his paper you  can transform matrices to different 1 counts while preserving determinant.  Also Will Orrick might know of recent work.

Comment: Also, using block matrices and certain constructions (cf Zivkovic, Schmidt, Paseman), one can give an exponential lower bound on your curve up to n^2/4 roughly.

Comment: For $n=6,7$, are the maximums achieved for matrices with constant row and column sums?

Comment: For $n=7$, the maximum of 32 is achieved (uniquely) by the incidence matrix of the $2-(7,4,2)$ design (complement of the Fano) so row and column sums are all 4. For n=6 there are 7 extremal ones, some regular some not.

Comment: Let me mention some recent progress here. If $d$ is small (by which I mean $d\leqslant n$), then the maximal determinant of a $0$-$1$ matrix $A$ with at most size(A)+d ones is at least $2^{d/3}\approx 1.26^d$ and at most $1.29^d$. (See Conjecture 4 in https://bit.ly/2LeXqSW and the note https://bit.ly/2swpF7O.)

Comment: In a [recent article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01892) Igor Araujo, József Balogh, and Yuzhou Wang prove the conjecture of Bruhn and Rautenbach mentioned by @Yaroslaw. See also OEIS [A301370](https://oeis.org/A301370) for related material.

Comment: The `bit.ly` links in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/751416) above point to the following papers. 
For Conjecture 4: _Bruhn, Henning; Rautenbach, Dieter_, [**Maximal determinants of combinatorial matrices**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2018.04.030), Linear Algebra Appl. 553, 37-57 (2018). [Zbl 1393.15025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1393.15025). For the note: _Shitov, Yaroslav_, [**On the determinant of a sparse 0-1 matrix**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2018.05.019), Linear Algebra Appl. 554, 49-50 (2018). [Zbl 1393.15041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1393.15041).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [this paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/article1119.html?sid=1119) Gasper, Pfoertner and Sigg prove an interesting upper bound for a real $n\times n$ matrix $M$: Let $n\alpha$ and $n\beta$ be the sum of the entries or the squares of the entries of $M$, respectively. Set $\delta=(\alpha^2-\beta)/(n-1)$. If $\delta\ge0$, then $\lvert\det M\rvert\le \alpha(\beta-\delta)^{(n-1)/2}$.

So $\alpha=\beta=k/n$ for a $(0,1)$-matrix. In contrast to the Hadamard bound, this bound is attained quite often for $(0,1)$-matrices, namely for the incidence matrices of symmetric block designs. Looking at their (somewhat involved) proof, this result is not surprising, for they show that upon fixing $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $n$, the maximum of the determinant is attained if $MM^t$ is a linear combination of the identity matrix and the all $1$ matrix.

Comment: Do they give a bound when delta is negative?

Comment: Yes, in this case $\lvert\det M\rvert\le\beta^{n/2}$.

Comment: Markus Sigg has written a [follow up](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02897) of our cited paper, fixing an error in the proof of the cited theorem and showing some new examples related to (0,1) matrices.

Answer (score 9):

The argument used in Hadamard's inequality works here too: If $A$ is the matrix, then ${\rm tr}(A^{t}A) = k,$ so if $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}, \ldots, \lambda_{n}$ are the (real, non-negative) eigenvalues of $A^{t}A$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i} =k.$ Hence $|{\rm det}(A)| = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{\frac{1}{2}}  \leq \left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}} \right)^{n}.$  The determinant is obviously $0$ if $k < n.$

( Later edit: I don't know whether this might be useful, but if we let $J$ be the all $1$'s matrix, note that if the $\alpha$-eigenspace of $A$ has dimension greater than $1,$ it non-trivially intersects the $0$ eigenspace of $J,$ which has dimension $n-1.$ Hence $-\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $J-A,$ which is also a $\{0,1\}$-matrix, but with $n^{2}-k$ non-zero entries. Even later edit, somewhat related (indirectly, I think)  to Peter Mueller's comment: in particular, if ${\rm rank}(J-A) <n-1,$ then $J$ and $J-A$ have a common non-zero eigenvector with eigenvalue $0,$ so also ${\rm det}(A) = 0).$

Comment: The determinant is $0$ too if $k>n^2-n+1$, because then there are two rows filled with $1$'s only.